# KeyError when running codes to read file from google drive in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I want to read a file directly from Google Drive using the Google Drive API on Visual Studio Code using Python.

Here is a part of codes:

```
file2 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['<the file ID of my file that is inside the Google Drive>']})
file2.GetContentString('testing.csv')
```

Upon running this, I get a

> `KeyError: KeyError('<the file ID of my file that is inside the Google Drive>')`

I searched on the internet the possible ways to solve this but nothing seems to work so far...

I followed this tutorial: [Hands-on tutorial for managing Google Drive files with Python](https://medium.com/@measurespace/hands-on-tutorial-for-managing-google-drive-files-with-python-ec20d917c114)

Comment: `file2 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['id']})`
`file2.GetContentFile('testing.csv')`

Comment: @ChatterOne i still get the same error...

Comment: @user14489561 your statement says you want to read a file from Google drive.  Your code says you are trying to create a file incorrectly in google drive.   What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DalmTo as in read the data of the csv file (that is stored inside the google drive) and display the data of the csv file in the output terminal of my visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

## uploading a file to google drive

The you need to send the `MediaFileUpload` for a file to be [uploaded](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python)

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

## view uploaded file on google drive web application.

using file [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) you get a [File resporce](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) response.  If the file you have uploaded is of a type that Google drive can open and display it will have an property called.

> webViewLink    string  A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.

You can use that link to open the file over in the Google drive web application.  However note that the user opening the file must have permissions on this file to be able to view it.

## reading data programmitclly.

Remember Google drive api is just a file storage api it doesn't have the ability to open files it just stores them.   If your working with an CSV then you should consider converting it to a google sheet and then using the Google Sheets api to access the data programmaticlly

Comment: @DalmTo the csv file is already uploaded in the google drive tho... i just have to read the data of that csv file and display it in my google drive

Comment: Do a file.get and then check for a webviewlink.  This will only work if its a type of file that Google drive can open.

Answer (score 0):

### `{'id': file1['id']}` implies that you want to retrieve the `id` of `file1` - a file that you are expected to have uploaded in previous steps

If you did not define `file1` in your code, you can hardcode instead the valid id of any file on your Drive as parameter.

Sample:

```py
file2 = drive.CreateFile({'id': '<the file ID of a csv file on your Google Drive>'})
file2.GetContentString('testing.csv')
```